# Qual è il contrario di "le temperature salgono"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrase-request, vocabulary

Nel linguaggio comune, quando si parla del tempo, come si esprime il  contrario di "le temperature salgono"? Le temperature calano? Le temperature si abbassano? Le temperature diminuiscono? Le temperature scendono?

Comment: Per la salita, si dice anche "le temperature aumentano", "crescono", "si alzano", "si impennano" (se è una salita rapida).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A seconda della zona d'Italia in cui ti trovi, puoi trovare tutti i modi che hai citato.
Nel sud d'Italia, ho spesso sentito utilizzare l'espressione 
"Le temperature scendono / si abbassano".

Al nord ho sentito spesso la prima che hai citato col verbo *calare*.

Answer (score 2):

Sono tutti utilizzabili, ma forse quello che personalmente uso di più è `le temperature scendono`.

Answer (score 0):

Non so la risposta grammaticalmente corretta, ma quella che mi sembra più formale è "Le temperature si abbassano". 
Invece, "la temperatura scende" mi sembra molto più informale e usato nel parlato.